# New build next to existing slab

Tags: concrete, foundation

I want to build a new structure, with walk out basement joining up to an existing structure that has a slab foundation.  Is this possible? what about the slab/footer for the existing structure, how do I create the new footer which will be deeper than the existing footer?  Is there a book I can read.  I am not doing the work, I just want to understand so when I find a builder I can have confidence in what I ask him to do.  Thanks

Comment: from what you have said it sounds very much like you need to approach an engineering professional to address the problem. It all sounds fixable but there a lot of details to work out first.